# PHP ghost script still contain color in detect ink coverage -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov E:/myfile.pdf but the myfile.pdf always have black font

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript, unoconv

I successfully  converted a .doc to pdf using this command:

```
$result = exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\python.exe"
D:\wamp\www\doc_to_pdf\libobasis4.4-pyuno\unoconv -f pdf -o
D:/wamp/www/doc_to_pdf/files/'.$pdf_File_name.'
D:/wamp/www/doc_to_pdf/files/'.$doc_file_name);
```

the reference at [Convert Word doc, docx and Excel xls, xlsx to PDF with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php), also using openoffice and unoconv.. When I convert document with all font color black.. the ghostscript detect still contain `color -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov E:/myfile.pdf`

How to fix it?

Comment: what is a "gost script detect"?

Comment: sorry thats a typo, the correcct is ghost script the docs here https://www.ghostscript.com/, i use ghost sript to detect total inkk coverage

Comment: Hm, you mean that it does not look like this `Page 57
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.04758 CMYK OK' with only the last K (black) column nonzero?

Comment: had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299574/ghostscript-color-detection?answertab=votes#tab-top ? Which would basically say if all columns are equal it will also look black(gray)

Comment: @StefanHegny yes do not like this example Page 1 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.04758 CMYK OK,,,, my file doccument contain all black font,, but ghost script still detect color..

Comment: but when i convert my document in https://www.freepdfconvert.com/,, the ghost script  detect all black font , and the correct result like,, Page 1 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.04758 CMYK OK